# Could the cv2.connectedComponents() process the grayscale images?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

When I just pass the grayscale image to this function like this:

```
img = cv.imread(path)
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, labels = cv.connectedComponents(img_gray, 8)
gray = np.array(labels)
```

I could receive the same connected components analysis result if I have converted the grayscale image to a binary image like this :

```
img = cv.imread(path)
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh = cv.threshold(img_gray,0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
_, labels = cv.connectedComponents(thresh, 8)
gray = np.array(labels)
```

I am a little bit curious about why it could process the grayscale image and get the same result ?
isn't it that the image should be a binary image?

Comment: 0 is background, any value > 0 is foreground

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to do the components analysis on thoses pixels that have the value > 0 . So I just use the cv.threshold(img_gray,0,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY).